# Android:Issue with identifying layout exists or not

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, layout, android-resources

I am dynamically creating linear layout in my application.At some stage i need to check if certain layout already exist or not and write logic accordingly

```
1)if layout present-remove all child views and replace with new childs
2)if layout not present-create layout with it's child elements
```

However i dont have problem with above two conditins but i have used the method as like below

```
linearLayout.setId(1);
```

while creation dynamic layouts
   now i want to check if layout with id **1** present or not what i tried as follows:

```
int layoutId = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier("1", "layout", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(layoutId), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (layoutId == 0 ) {
                // this layout doesn't exist
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "layout not present", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "layout  present", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

If i give any string in getIdentifier() method as first parameter then it works fine.

**But problem is here**

It always returns me non-zero number if i gave any digit in double quotes as first parameter in getIdentifier() method.So i get always else block executed if the layout either present or not.

Comment: @Dhiraj change parameter 1st one is ur string and 2nd one will be id

Comment: int buttonId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("gameButton", "id", this.getPackageName());

Comment: @Tufan ok i am trying and let u knw